# Is there a way to use an existing Elastic Block Store (EBS) with an FME Cloud instance?

Tags: fme-form, amazon-ec2, fme-flow-hosted

I am seeing help topics for all items except `Resources`.  What is the best way to make EBS data available to FME Cloud instance? Would I need to make it available via one of my own EC2 instances?

Or download it locally and upload via the usual FME-Cloud upload?

[image]

Comment: FME is a spatial data product and FME questions are on-topic.You should probably ask if you are not sure what the product is before down-voting. Or hover over the FME tag for a second and read the popup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe we have support in FME Cloud for Amazon EBS, although from the look of it it's something we could well do in the future. Ping an email to our support team and a Server/Cloud expert there will know more than I do.

FME Cloud does have the ability to integrate data from other cloud storage facilities. In particular we have S3Uploader and S3Downloader transformers to read/write data directly from Amazon S3, and Readers/Writers for Amazon DynamoDB and Amazon Redshift. There are also HTTP transformers that would let you read/write to other web services, and Readers/Writers for Google tools (Google Maps Engine - GME, and Fusion Tables) plus Microsoft (SQL Server/Azure).

The Resources functionality is probably the most 'beta' of what is on FME Cloud. It's a new tool to let you manage file-based data on an FME Server. Previously the standard method was to publish data with the workspace, but then that doesn't let you manage or re-use it. This functionality lets you publish data and then use it for any translation. It's going to be most useful in FME Cloud because there you don't get the opportunity to log in to the machine itself to manage data.